# Pandas convert all columns into data entries and create new column for their current values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a weird .csv file where it consists of COVID cases in each US county from January to the present day. However, while county and state are their own unique columns, every single date (1/01/20, 2/01/20, etc) from Jan 1st to October 20th is its own unique column, containing the number of cases in that county on that day. How do I convert this in pandas to a form where I have a date column and a cases column instead?

Link to the .csv from its source: https://usafactsstatic.blob.core.windows.net/public/data/covid-19/covid_confirmed_usafacts.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do the "reverse" operation of what's called a pivot.

Let's get straight first what you want. Currently the table looks like this

```
State   | County   | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 | ...
Alabama | Whatever | 10    | 20    | 3     | ...
Arizona | ...
```

So you have one row for each State/County pair and then a column for each day.

What you **want** is a "stacked" version:

```
State   | County   | Date  | Cases
Alabama | Whatever | Day 1 | 10
Alabama | Whatever | Day 2 | 20
Alabama | Whatever | Day 3 | 3
...
```

I suggest checking out this section then:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt

Looks like `melt` is just your ticket!